# Select não funciona Mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte select

```
select nm_login,ds_Senha from tb_funcionario where cd_funcionario=?
```

Só que se o campo `ds_status` for igual a admin quero que ignore `cd_funcionario=?`, para mostrar todos os usuarios.

Comment: Acho que não expliquei direito, teoricamente o que eu quero é isso quando o ds_status for 'admin' quero que ele execute isso
select nm_login,ds_Senha from tb_funcionario;
senao
select nm_login,ds_Senha from tb_funcionario where cd_funcionario=?

Comment: E esse status vem de onde? De outra tabela? Ou é uma constante?

Comment: Você tem que fazer o uso de CASE mas como não postou a estrutura da tabela, não tenho como te ajudar por favor reformule sua pergunta poste a estrutura e explique melhor a idéia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma PROCEDURE para manipular essa situação. Segue um simples exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que isso não é a solução para o projeto pois estou usando nomes de campos fictícios, é apenas uma procedure que se adequa a questão.
Copiar e colar apenas, não ira funcionar a não ser que esteja usando o mesmo nome de campos(ID_Funcionario, nm_login, ds_senha, ds_acesso, Nome_Usuario) e o mesmo nome da tabela(tbl_Funcionarios).

Outra coisa em questão é o campo "ds_senha" para quem declarei o parâmetro @ds_senha do tipo VARCHAR. Se o campo/coluna usa um tipo de criptografia para senha vc tem que adicionar a função para descriptografar antes da condição IF ELSE.

Segue abaixo com solicitado pelo colega...

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE Autenticar(@nm_login VARCHAR, @ds_senha VARCHAR)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ID INT;

   /*Com esse SELECT você captura o ID do funcionário.*/
   SELECT @ID = ID_Funcionario FROM tbl_Funcionarios WHERE Nome_Usuario = @nm_login;

   IF (SELECT ds_status FROM Funcionarios WHERE Nome_Usuario = @nm_login) = 'Admin' THEN
      /*Se o SELECT acima retorna Admin do campo ds_status*/
      SELECT nm_login, ds_senha FROM tbl_Funcionarios;

   ELSE
      /*Se o SELECT acima retorna algo diferente de Admin do campo ds_status*/
      SELECT nm_login, ds_senha FROM tbl_Funcionarios WHERE ID_Funcionario = @ID;
   END IF
END
DELIMITER//
```

Comment: Legal, mas poste o código aqui em texto. Imagem é ruim pra ler em celular e quase impossível de copiar e colar :)

Comment: Vou editar e add abaixo da imagem @rodorgas